# Mule Requests are failing

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I have a global http listener. I am using this listener for all my API calls. when one of the API call fails due to any json parsing issue, etc? then all the other API calls are also getting failed. and the failed api call or code flow doesn't gets used in the other api calls. still all the subsequent API requests are failing until we restart the runtime(MULE ESB stand alone) again.

Following the Global Exception Strategy that we have implemented.

```
 <choice-exception-strategy name="globalException">
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException) &amp;&amp; message.inboundProperties.'http.status'==409]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;File Not Downloaded.&quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;Your Search Did Not Fetch Anything!&quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(java.sql.SQLException)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;Malformed Query &quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) &amp;&amp; 501==flowVars.errorCode]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;File Not Downloaded. &quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) &amp;&amp; 404==flowVars.errorCode]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;Unauthorized To Download &quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) &amp;&amp; 401==flowVars.errorCode]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;Unauthorized Access &quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.MessagingException) &amp;&amp; 127==flowVars.con_id]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;Did Not Fetch Anything!&quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.MessagingException)]">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;Invalid Credentials Cannot Proceed Further&quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="{&quot;error&quot;: &quot;#[exception.getMessage().replaceAll(&quot;\'&quot;,&quot;&quot;).replaceAll(&quot;\&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;).replaceAll(&quot;\n&quot;,&quot;&quot;)]&quot;}" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

Below is the way we are parsing the input json.

```
<set-payload value="#[payload.data]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <set-variable  variableName="structure" value="#[json:structure]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="jsonRequestData" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[String input = payload;    
payload = new org.json.JSONObject(input);]]></expression-component>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
```

This is not happening on a local environment. Any clues to debug this issue?

your help is highly appreciated on this.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that if an api call at /endpoint2 is successful, then a call to /endpoint1 fails, a subsequent call to /endpoint2 fails? How is your HTTP listener setup? What is the exception that you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand how your code is behaving and can you answer these questions?

1. What is the exception Strategy used? How are you parsing JSON ..
2. Is it some transformer or Dataweave?  If you are using Transformer,
   are  you handling the `org.mule.api.transformer.*` exception?
3. If you are using Dataweave, are you handling  the
   `'com.mulesoft.weave.*'`exception?
4. Does your code handling the default exception Strategy?

Now can you try this..During the API calls did you used any success status validation codes ?This should be configured in HTTP component -->advanced--> and put 200..599

```
       <http:success-status-code-validator values="200..599"/>
```

Comment: Hi Kamal, Thanks for your response!                                                                     #1: I have updated the question with how are we following the exception strategy implementation and input json parsing.           
 #2: We use Transformer. Yes, we are handling the exceptions.                                        
 #3: we are not using the dataweave.                                                                 
 #4: Yes. we do.

Comment: can you try this...during the api call, configure the success validation code from 200..500

Comment: Well, we are not using the HTTP Requests here. we are using http listeners and these are REST API Calls with POST. we dont see any issue with GET Calls.